# How to understand the use of minimal Dirac Hamiltonian in the ten-fold way topological classification?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, hamiltonian, topological-insulators, time-reversal-symmetry

Chiu *et al*. published a paper in 2016 [1] to provide a classification scheme for topological insulators and superconductors based on non-spatial symmetries. The main idea is to use the minimal Dirac Hamiltonian to take place in realistic systems with symmetries classified by time-reversal symmetry ($T$), particle-hole symmetry ($C$) and chiral symmetry ($S$). The minimal Dirac Hamiltonian is defined as follow:

$$H_{D}(\pmb{k})=M\tilde{\gamma_0}+\sum_{j=1}^D m_j \tilde{\gamma_j}+\sum_{i=1}^d k_i \gamma_i,\tag 1$$

where $M$ and $m_j$ are constants representing mass terms related to the band gap, $D$ is the number of possible symmetry preserving extra mass terms (SPEMTs), $d$ is the dimension of the system, and $\tilde{\gamma_0}$, $\tilde{\gamma_j}$ and $\gamma_i$ are Gamma matrices that anticommute with each other and whose squares are equal to the identity matrix, that is:

$$\{\gamma_i,\gamma_j\}=2\delta_{ij},\{\tilde{\gamma_i},\tilde{\gamma_j}\}=2\delta_{ij},\{\gamma_i,\tilde{\gamma_j}\}=0.\tag 2$$

By comparing the minimal dimensions of the Gamma matrices when a SPEMT exists ($D=1$) or not ($D=0$), they obtained this result:

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

*Here is my question: since the anticommutation condition in Eq (2) does not necessarily exist in realistic systems, why does the result still apply to them?*

---

Here I use an example to illustrate my question more clearly. In class AII with $T^2=-1$ (e.g. a regular electronic system taking into account spin-orbit coupling) and in two dimensions, a minimal Dirac Hamiltonian without a SPEMT ($D=0$) is expressed as:

$$H_{D}(k_1,k_2)=M\tilde{\gamma_0}+k_1 \gamma_1+k_2 \gamma_2.\tag 3$$

Using Clifford algebra, we are able to determine the minimal dimension of the matrices, which is $4\times4$. Without loss of generality, we can rewrite Eq (3) as:

$$H_{D}(k_1,k_2)=M\tau_x \sigma_0+k_1 \tau_z \sigma_x+k_2 \tau_z \sigma_y,\tag 4$$

when the time-reversal operator is written as $T=i\tau_0 \sigma_y K$. Such a Hamiltonian is invariant under the time-reversal symmetry, i.e.

$$TH_{D}(k_1,k_2)T^{-1}=H_{D}(-k_1,-k_2).\tag 5$$

When a SPEMT $m_1\tilde{\gamma_1}$ is added to Eq (3), we will find that there is no matirce with dimension $4\times4$ that can simultaneously satisfy Eq (2) and Eq (5) unless we use $8\times8$ matrices instead. Eq (4) describes such a system where the band gap is only manipulated by the parameter $M$, and the topological trivial and non-trivial phases are represented by $M$ and $-M$, respectively.

However, in a realistic system, the anticommutation condition in Eq (2) is not necessary. Thus the Hamiltonian is written as:

$$H_{D}(k_1,k_2)=\sum_{i,j=0,x,y,z}d_{ij}(k_1,k_2)\tau_i \sigma_j,\tag 6$$

instead of Eq (1), where $d_{ij}(k_1,k_2)$ are real functions. Such a Hamiltonian is much more complicated, why are the results derived from the minimal Dirac Hamiltonian in Eq (1) still applicable?

---

Reference:

[1] Classification of topological quantum matter with symmetries. [DOI: 10.1103/RevModPhys.88.035005](https://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.88.035005)